Saving file to a Sony handycam
For a project, I want to put a file into a Sony handycam, I tried some software like multiAVCHD or BDedit to recreate or edit the structure, but I can't get it to work.
At best, when I try to view the file on the camera (HDR-PJ420) I get a black screen and then the camera freeze, or it's says "Error while reading"
Same, all the tools I can get are more (of course) about put files from the cam to the computer and not the other way around.
What's a working solution for doing that ?
Thank you for you help !

Are you using a hex editor to check if the file structures are matching? We need a short test file to advise about. Try to make a 5 second HandyCam file and share it for analysis. What programming language do you use to create/edit file bytes?

@VC.One I'm not and don't quite have clues about how to, I'll look it up!
Here is an example file :
https://github.com/asecondaccount/download-video-to-camera/blob/main/00025.MTS
